# Maximum Supported RAM in a Sony Vaio VPCW12J1E

Tags: memory, ddr2

I have this Sony Vaio 10.1 inch laptop which has 1 GB ddr2 RAM and runs on an Intel Atom N280 at 1.66 GHz.

My question is what is the maximum amount of RAM this laptop supports? It has only one slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google says 2GB is the max. So , no , you cannot put 4gb.

Comment: According to the [Crucial Memory Advisor](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for//vaio-vpcw12j1e) the machine indeed only supports 2GB of memory. You will likely see an improvement going from 1GB to 2GB if you open a lot of programs simultaneously or run a program (i.e. Photoshop) that uses a lot of memory.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb Netbooks top out at 2GB RAM. The only exception is if the Netbook is pretty new. This isn't the case though.

Comment: I see. The notebook it's pretty great. I run linux on it but an improvement would be great. I suppose a 2gb ram and an ssd would do that for it. I just hoped it would take a 4gb ram. Thanks for the asnwers